# Appending an empty list with list in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def permute(nums):
    result = []
    get_permute([], nums, result)
    return result

def get_permute(current, num, result):

    if not num:
        result.append(current+[])

    for i, v in enumerate(num):
        current.append(num[i])
        get_permute(current, num[:i] + num[i + 1:], result)
        current.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    r = permute([1,2,3])

    for perm in r:
        print(perm)
```

What does `current + []` do in `result.append(current+[])` if I remove `+[]` it printing blank lists.

Answer (score 4):

It's making a copy of the list.  When you remove it, you run into the [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) problem, because the outer list contains many references to the same list, instead of references to many different lists.

You should be able to replace it with `current.copy()` (using Python >= 3.3) or `list(current)` to avoid similar confusion among future readers.  (There are [a lot of ways to copy a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).  Pick the one you like and stick with it.)

Answer (score 2):

## What does the `+ []` do?

It generates a new list with the same contents as the old list.

```
>>> x = [1]
>>> id(x) == id(x + [])
False
>>> x == x + []
True
```

## Why do I need this?

Whitout adding copies to your result, you would have the same list many times in your result and everytime you update that list, it affects your result.

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> result = []
>>> result.append(x)
>>> x.append(3)
>>> result.append(x)
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Some possible ways to make the could more readable would be

```
result.append(current[:])
```

or

```
result.append(list(current))
```

## Why does it return blank lists if you remove the `+ []`?

Because if you do not append copies to the result, there would be just one list in the result but multiple times. And you call `.append(num[i])` on this list just as often as `.pop()`, which results in that list be empty.